# android:state_enabled missing/not working?

Tags: android, xml, properties, state

I do not have the property android:state_enabled for any of the controls. Typing it manually doesn't work either. I can only use the deprecated android:enabled.

I have the latest everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this answer from a similar thread: it says android:enabled is not actually deprecated, it's just an Eclipse error.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6919200/813810

Answer (score 5):

How exactly are you using the state_enabled property?
It is a read-only property to check if the view is enabled, not to set the view as enabled/disabled! Please check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html

As an example, I am using the following code that works since Android 1.5, check if it works for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/image_disabled" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_enabled" />
</selector>
```

Comment: This doesn't work on 2.1. "state_enabled" doesn't exist at all in the XML. Simply "enabled" does though.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't exist? I think that eclipse does not auto-complete / list it, but it does exist. Have you tried the abovementioned code? You'll see that if you use the selector I posted the view's drawable will change when the state of the view changes from enabled to disabled

Comment: I'm not in front of the environment right now, but it wouldn't compile at all stating an XML error.

Comment: Are you sure you are placing the android:state_enabled property in the correct xml? Are you using it in a selector (like in the response I gave) or are you trying to use it somewhere else? Because android:state_enabled is a valid property, as you can see here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html

Comment: Hi, I had was also confused by the "depraved" comment on "enabled" and couldn't find "state_enabled" in XML. Unlike Kurian, I could type it in manually. However, as it didn't have the same effect as "enabled" I don't really see why it should replace it.

Answer (score 0):

android:state_enabled was introduced in API level 14. If you use API < 14 the android:state_enabled won't work;     [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

Comment: I think that's not true. android:state_activated has been introduced in API 11 and android:state_hovered has been introduced in API 14, but android:state_enabled is there since API 1.