# Android checkbox state_enabled

Tags: android, eclipse, checkbox, deprecated

the xml element "enabled" for a checkbox is deprecated. Eclipse tells me to use state_enabled instead. I tried to add

```
android:state_enabled="false"
```

to my checkbox within my xml instead of

```
android:enabled="false"
```

But it doesn't show any effect. The latter one does the desired. I don't want to use a deprecated method. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

This [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/967de0cb1388811) discusses this.  Romain Guy says it is not deprecated but perhaps some bug/issue in Eclipse or the ADT editor causes it to show up in the deprecated section.

Comment: well the android command line tool lint.exe also says it's deprecated